# JDK availability in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud, javac, cloud-foundry, java

I am trying to call javac from within a Cloud Foundry Java app to compile a java file during runtime of the app. I have a question about which JDK is being used.

To test this, in my app, I instantiated a JavaCompiler using statement ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() and print out the compiler instance. The app was deployed on CF and printed out:   **com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool@2e68d3ad**

The following came from the log.

-----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.13 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#03b493f
2017-04-24T13:23:21.38-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> **Downloading Open Jdk JRE** 1.8.0_121 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_121.tar.gz (0.5s)
2017-04-24T13:23:22.48-0700 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.0s)

Two questions:

1. Is it safe to assume a JDK is always available on Cloud Foundry, so I can use javac.
2. Why the compiler instantiated in my code refers to Sun's javac? I was expecting OpenJDK JDK( even though the log said only the JRE is downloaded ).

Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks.
-Michelle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume a JDK is always available on Cloud Foundry, so I can use javac.

The `javac` utility is not installed by the build pack.  If you look closely at what it is installing, you'll see that it's installing a JRE and not a JDK.  The JRE is just the runtime and does not contain `javac`.

> 2017-04-24T13:23:21.38-0700 [STG/0] OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_121 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_121.tar.gz (0.5s)

Note how it says "Open JDK JRE".  "Open JDK" is the name of the Java implementation and "JRE" is the type.

You can confirm by running `cf ssh` into an app deployed with the Java build pack.  If you look at `/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/`, you can see what all is installed.

This is all that I see under the `bin` directory.

```
~/app/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre$ ls bin/
java                                            jcmd  jmap    keytool      orbd     policytool  rmiregistry  tnameserv
java-buildpack-memory-calculator-2.0.2_RELEASE  jjs   jstack  killjava.sh  pack200  rmid        servertool   unpack200
```

> Why the compiler instantiated in my code refers to Sun's javac? I was expecting OpenJDK JDK( even though the log said only the JRE is downloaded ).

I suspect that it's because OpenJDK came out of Sun, so there is still some shared heritage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK#History

Comment: Can confirm: OpenJDK was led by Sun and is now being led by Oracle. For proof look at the copyright in any OpenJDK source file: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5534221c23fc. It contains various `*.oracle.*` packages as well as `*.sun.*` packages. To verify if it's OpenJDK or not, look at the output of `java -version`.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment and expanded on @whjte's question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927417/cloudfoundry-and-jdk/63944051#63944051