# Open JDK Like Memory Calculator Error Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I am deploying spring boot hello world app to cloud foundry. Used cf push command.Getting below Error:

```
Open JDK Memory Calculator Error: No Version Reasonable for '2.0.2_RELEASE' in 3.13.0_RELEASE
```

Any one have idea about this?
From below stackoverflow, I can see 2.0.2.RELEASE as open jdk version:
[JDK availability in Cloud Foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622494/jdk-availability-in-cloud-foundry)
I am unable to get 3.13.0_RELEASE?

Complete Log:

```
Updating app TestPOC1...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 256.00 KiB / 256.00 KiB [=====================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 1s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 919f72a9-975c-4bf3-8b2f-1f0e73bda65b creating container for instance 0597e6a8-7b92-4c71-8942-15c68c29b535
   Cell 919f72a9-975c-4bf3-8b2f-1f0e73bda65b successfully created container for instance 0597e6a8-7b92-4c71-8942-15c68c29b535
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (16.2M)
   [Buildpack]                      ERROR Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: Open JDK Like Memory Calculator error: No version resolvable for '2.0.2_RELEASE' in 3.13.0_RELEASE>
   Open JDK Like Memory Calculator error: No version resolvable for '2.0.2_RELEASE' in 3.13.0_RELEASE
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 1
   Exit status 223
   Cell 919f72a9-975c-4bf3-8b2f-1f0e73bda65b stopping instance 0597e6a8-7b92-4c71-8942-15c68c29b535
   Cell 919f72a9-975c-4bf3-8b2f-1f0e73bda65b destroying container for instance 0597e6a8-7b92-4c71-8942-15c68c29b535
   Cell 919f72a9-975c-4bf3-8b2f-1f0e73bda65b successfully destroyed container for instance 0597e6a8-7b92-4c71-8942-15c68c29b535
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

Comment: It is trying to install a version that doesn't exist, 2.0.2.RELEASE, while only 3.13.0_RELEASE exists in your buildpack. What version of the JBP are you using? Are you setting any prefixed `JBP_*` env variables? Those can impact the version being installed. Output of `cf env` would be helpful to determine that. The full output of `cf push` would be helpful too, everything including the command & your manifest.yml up through to the point where it fails.

Comment: I haven't explicitly mentioned about JBP version in manifest.yml file. Output of ```cf env``` does not show JBP version number. At first, configured 4.2 java build pack and downgraded to 3.9 now. Then started this error.

Comment: OK, first, don't use 3.9. It's super old. I think you can also see weirdness when you switch between something that old and something new. What I would suggest is that you `cf delete` the app, then push again or `cf push` with a new app name. Either will clear out what is cached by the buildpack for your app and I think it should make this go away. Or switch back to 4.LATEST and use that. You should really try to run on the latest possible version to make sure you're getting the latest JVM updates.

Comment: Makes sense @Daniel. My organization cloud foundry account has java build pack 3.9 latest. That is why trying to run app on build pack v3.9.

Comment: OK, if you have to move back to v3.9 just do so with a fresh app, like I mentioned above. That should avoid weird issues like this.

Comment: @Vipul - Were you able to solved this issue ?

Comment: Yes, What is your cf push command? what version of build pack are you using? In my case, build pack is the culprit. I am using the latest one now, no issue then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [a CloudFundry issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/328) which according to [this comment](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/328#issuecomment-278970401) is solved by [updating stack to trusty](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/stacks.html).

It seems that [precise stack](https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/precise/x86_64/index.yml) doesn't support version 2.0.2_RELEASE while [trusty stack](https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/index.yml) does. Somehow [bionic stack](https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/bionic/x86_64/index.yml) only works with 3.X.

Comment: I tried 'cf push testpoc1 -s cflinusfs3' and same result. What do you mean by precise stack, trusty stack and bionic stack?

Comment: `cflinuxfs2      Cloud Foundry Linux-based filesystem - Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LT` is based on Ubuntu Trusty as per the docs.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774751/spring-cloud-foundry-issue-223?