# CloudFoundry and JDK

Tags: java, spring, deployment, cloud-foundry

I'm struggling with the deployment of a spring app that needs to compile java code during runtime. My app calls the javac command when a user submits a solution to a problem, so it can later run java

I'm deploying to cloud foundry and using the java-buildpack, but unfortunately, it doesn't come with JDK, only JRE is available and that thing has no javac or java commands available.

Do you guys know a way on how to add JDK to cloud foundry, without having to write my own custom buildpack.

Thanks

Comment: `that thing has no javac or java commands available` -> The JRE won't have `javac` but it will have `java`. the JBP doesn't put Java on the path though, so you either need to set PATH properly or use a full path to the JRE binaries. It's going to be under `~/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use multi-buildpack support and use the apt-buildpack to install a JDK. It should work fine alongside the JBP. It just needs to be first in the list.

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack
```

Example:

1. Create an apt.yml.

   ```
    ---
    packages:
    - openjdk-11-jdk-headless
   ```
2. Bundle that into your JAR, `jar uf path/to/your/file.jar apt.yml`. It should be added to the root of the JAR, so if you `jar tf path/to/your/file.jar` you should see just `apt.yml` and nothing prefixed to it.
3. Update your manifest.yml. Add the apt-buildpack first in the list.

   ```
    ---
    applications:
    - name: spring-music
      memory: 1G
      path: build/libs/spring-music-1.0.jar
      buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack#v0.2.2
      - java_buildpack
   ```
4. Then `cf push`. You should see the apt-buildpack run and install the JDK. It'll then be installed under `~/deps/0/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`. It does not appear to end up on the PATH either, so use a full path to `javac` or update the path.